# how to allow multi domain jquery validate

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

This is custom method in jquery validation example how to allow more than one domain in email

```
$.validator.addMethod("baseEmail", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9ąćęłńóśżźĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŻŹ._-]+@(yahoo\.com|gmail\.com|hotmail\.com)$/i.test(value);

}, "Only this domains are allowed (gmail, yahoo, hotmail)");
```

html code

```
<form action="" name="form" id="form">
  <div class="field">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="required">
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <input type="submit" value="Validate!">
</div>
```

jquery code

```
$("#form").validate({
highlight: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.field').removeClass('success').addClass('errorBlock');     
        },
        success: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.field').removeClass('errorBlock').addClass('success');
        },
rules: {
  email : { 
    required: true,
    email: true,
    baseEmail: true }
},
messages:{
    email:{
        required: "required",
        email: "email is required",

    }
}
}); 
});
```

So you can valid email address and add multi domain support via this code.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and a proper problem description including troubleshooting steps you have taken. A demo would be very helpful

Comment: this full code explanation what i wanted to achive